# Checkbox to uncheck all other checkboxes

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyqt5, qcheckbox

I'm trying to put in some validation such that:

- When either **"Select A"** or **"Select B"** is checked, **"None Selected"** is automatically unchecked
- When "None Selected" is checked, both **"Select A"** and **"Select B"** are automatically unchecked

But when I run this code, clicking any checkbox will uncheck **all** the 3 checkboxes.

i.e. The window initializes with **"None Selected"** checked. But when I click **"Select A"**, it unchecks **"None Selected"**, which is intended, but **"Select A"** doesn't get checked.

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
import sys
import PyQt5

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("None Selected")
        checkBoxA    = QCheckBox("Select A")
        checkBoxB    = QCheckBox("Select B")

        checkBoxNone.setChecked(True)
        checkBoxNone.stateChanged.connect(lambda checked: (checkBoxA.setChecked(False), checkBoxB.setChecked(False)))
        checkBoxA.stateChanged.connect(lambda checked: checkBoxNone.setChecked(False))
        checkBoxB.stateChanged.connect(lambda checked: checkBoxNone.setChecked(False))

        grid = QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(checkBoxNone, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(checkBoxA, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(checkBoxB, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()
    ex = Test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused because according to your requirements, you should only make those options if some `QCheckBox` is checked but you do not do that verification, to be able to handle it properly, create a slot and to know which object the signal was emited, the `sender()` method:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("None Selected")
        self.checkBoxA    = QCheckBox("Select A")
        self.checkBoxB    = QCheckBox("Select B")

        self.checkBoxNone.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBoxNone.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
        self.checkBoxA.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
        self.checkBoxB.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)

        grid.addWidget(self.checkBoxNone, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.checkBoxA, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.checkBoxB, 3, 0)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def onStateChange(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            if self.sender() == self.checkBoxNone:
                self.checkBoxA.setChecked(False)
                self.checkBoxB.setChecked(False)
            elif self.sender() in (self.checkBoxA, self.checkBoxB):
                self.checkBoxNone.setChecked(False)
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much. I actually spent hours Googling around for a solution, but none of the dozens of pages I've visited (many of them StackOverflow) addressed this particular problem.