# unselect and select all checkboxes in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcheckbox

similar to [Python PyQt - Checkbox to uncheck all other checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399579/python-pyqt-checkbox-to-uncheck-all-other-checkboxes)

I want to have a checkbox to

1. unselect all selected checkboxes.
2. And a checkbox to select all checkboxes

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView, QGridLayout, QWidget, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from functools import partial

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.font = QFont("Helvetica", 9)
        self.setFont(self.font)
        self.showMaximized()     
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]
        print('\npostions: ', positions)
        wordlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']


        for position, wordlist in zip(positions, wordlist): 
            checkB =(QCheckBox(wordlist)) 
            checkB.setStatusTip("Crawling best singals for "+wordlist+"." ) # set Statusbar
            checkB.stateChanged.connect(partial(self.checkState, wordlist))
            grid.addWidget(checkB, *position)

        checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("None Selected")
        checkBoxNone.setChecked(True)
        checkBoxNone.stateChanged.connect(self.checkState)
        grid.addWidget(checkBoxNone, 6, 1)

        checkAll = QCheckBox("Select All")
        checkAll.setChecked(False)
        checkAll.stateChanged.connect(self.selectAll)
        grid.addWidget(checkAll, 6, 2)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(grid) 
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)      

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

    # Here are the problems. 
    # Is it because I have create checkboxes with a for loop?

    def selectAll(self, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            if self.sender() == MainWindow.checkAll:
                MainWindow.checkB.setChecked(True)

    def checkState(self, checktext, state):
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            print(checktext)
            if self.sender() == MainWindow.checkBoxNone:
                MainWindow.checkB.setChecked(False)
            elif self.sender() == MainWindow.checkB:
                MainWindow.checkBoxNone.setChecked(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    mw = MainWindow()
```

How can I get a working code with this setup?

Comment: Explain better since you have added a new option: Select All. Let's say the user pressed "Select All" so all checkboxes are selected, and what if the user presses "Select All" again what should happen?

Comment: if user press "select all" checkbox, all checkboxes should be selected [checkB.setChecked(True)] . When user press again, nothing should happens. Same with "None Selected" checkbox. This checkbox chouuld unselect selected chechboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There various problems with your code.

1. you're trying to access *class* attributes such as `MainWindow.checkB`, `MainWindow.checkBoxNone`, etc. They do not exist. You should use *instance* attributes, using things like `self.checkB`;
2. to make the above work, you also have to *set* those attributes, so `checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("None Selected")` should be `self.checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("None Selected")`, etc.
3. you're connecting the `checkBoxNone.stateChanged` to a function that requires two positional arguments, but [`stateChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#stateChanged) only has one (the state); no check box signal returns the text;
4. in your functions you are not checking or unchecking any of the other checkboxes;
5. even assuming that you used the correct references (`self.checkBoxNone`, etc), you should never check an unchecked box (or the opposite) as a result of a stateChanged signal as you did in your code, because it will result in a recursion;
6. QMainWindow has its own layout, you *cannot* set your own; also, you are already going to set it for the central widget;

To make it work you should have some reference to all checkboxes you have created, and then apply the state you want, while being very careful about changing the check state of each box.

In the following example the "select all" and "select none" check boxes appear partially checked if, respectively, not all boxes are checked, or at least one is.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        # You *cannot* set a layout to a main window
        # self.setLayout(grid)

        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]
        wordlist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']


        # use a list to keep a reference to all checkboxes
        self.checkBoxes = []
        for position, word in zip(positions, wordlist): 
            checkB =(QCheckBox(word)) 
            checkB.setStatusTip("Crawling best singals for "+word+"." ) # set Statusbar
            checkB.stateChanged.connect(self.checkStates)
            grid.addWidget(checkB, *position)
            self.checkBoxes.append(checkB)

        self.checkBoxNone = QCheckBox("Select none")
        self.checkBoxNone.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        self.checkBoxNone.stateChanged.connect(
            partial(self.selectBoxes, False))
        grid.addWidget(self.checkBoxNone, 6, 1)

        self.checkBoxAll = QCheckBox("Select All")
        self.checkBoxAll.setCheckState(Qt.PartiallyChecked)
        self.checkBoxAll.stateChanged.connect(
            partial(self.selectBoxes, True))
        grid.addWidget(self.checkBoxAll, 6, 2)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(grid) 
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)      

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

    def checkStates(self):
        states = [c.isChecked() for c in self.checkBoxes]

        # temporarily block signals so that there is no recursive calls
        self.checkBoxAll.blockSignals(True)
        self.checkBoxNone.blockSignals(True)

        # set the "select all" fully checked too if all boxes are checked,
        # otherwise make it partially checked
        self.checkBoxAll.setCheckState(
            Qt.Checked if all(states) else Qt.PartiallyChecked)

        # set the "select none" unchecked only if all boxes are unchecked,
        # otherwise make it partially checked
        self.checkBoxNone.setCheckState(
            Qt.Unchecked if not any(states) else Qt.PartiallyChecked)

        # unblock signals back
        self.checkBoxAll.blockSignals(False)
        self.checkBoxNone.blockSignals(False)

    def selectBoxes(self, state):
        for check in self.checkBoxes:
            check.blockSignals(True)
            check.setChecked(state)
            check.blockSignals(False)
        self.checkStates()
```

That said, let me tell you that using a checkbox to do what you are doing is not suggested, as it is counterintuitive, both visually and from the point of view of interaction. It is better to use a button for checking everything and another one for unchecking.
Also, be careful when naming variables and attributes; for example, `checkAll` and `selectAll` are very similar, but they refer to two distinct and very different objects: a checkbox and a function; their names should reflect that difference also. While not following this principle does not represent a technical issue, it can become a problem when the number of objects (functions, attributes, etc) grows along with your program: using clear and descriptive names improves readability (and mental reference), which is an important aspect for both developing *and* issue tracking.
The same concept goes for loops: don't use `wordlist` for both the list and the iterator element.

Comment: very nice. How would be look the solution with the buttons?
And when I select one by one or "Select All" I want to get out  the checkbox text of each checkbox. So checkB call the method like:
checkB.stateChanged.connect(partial(self.checkStates, wordlist))
and 
def checkStates(self, word):
      print(word)

but this won't work. Why?

Comment: @sticki what doesn't work? If you do it exactly as you wrote, it will print the word. (by the way, you shouldn't reuse the same name for both a list and the iterator elements (use `for position, word in zip(positions, wordlist): checkB =(QCheckBox(word))` etc...)

Comment: everything is fine. Thank you very much.